# ERROR Invalid options in vue.config.js: "build" is not allowed. "dev" is not allowed

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I have an existing `vue-cli 2` app that I'm attempting to upgrade to `vue-cli-3`. After adding my unique dependencies,  I dropped `src/` right into the newly created `vue-cli-3` app and started up. *woot!*

How do I manage `[PROD|DEV|TEST].env.js` now that we use `vue.config.js`?

I got the following error because my first attempt to create a `vue.config.js` was to simply rename `config/index.js` to be `/vue.config.js` and keep the existing `/config/[PROD|DEV|TEST].env.js` but I got the following error:

```
ERROR  Invalid options in vue.config.js: "build" is not allowed. "dev" 
is not allowed error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I don't understand how environments are now managed.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5):

May be you should use `devServer` instead. And for `build` I guess there is another name now.

For example:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
   // your settings
  }
}
```

For example:

```
module.exports = {
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': {
        target: '<url>',
        ws: true,
        changeOrigin: true
      },
      '/foo': {
        target: '<other_url>'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Reference: [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#devserver)

Comment: excellent ! solved my problem and my port variable is set inside vue.config